# Import module with Japanese voiced kana name in python 3

Tags: python, macos, importerror

I have two python modules, `あいうえおけ` and `あいうえおげ` in `jp` directory.

I ran

```
>>> from jp import あいうえおけ
>>> from jp import あいうえおげ
```

on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 machine, and worked.

On Mac OSX,
importing the unvoiced kana `あいうえおけ` worked,
but importing the voiced kana `あいうえおげ` failed.

```
>>> from jp import あいうえおけ
>>> from jp import あいうえおげ
ImportError: cannot import name 'あいうえおげ'
```

Module names containing voiced kanas always failed.

What did cause this problem, python3 or compiler ?

My env:

```
MacOs 10.12.1 
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 15 2016, 07:38:42) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin
```

Comment: "MacOs 10.12.1" Is the filename encoded as "... U+3052" or as "... U+3051 U+3099"?

Comment: How should I check the filename? I printed this string in python3, got `...\u3052`

Comment: Not sure. You'd have to examine the filesystem at a low level.

Comment: `git status` show `modified:   "...\343\201\221.py" ` and `modified:   "...\343\201\222.py"`

Comment: That doesn't help. The VFS can frob the filename in between the application and the disk.